# Negative reputation received for a post I didn't make

Tags: bug

I just logged on and check my account to see that I have received -2 reputation because a post has been removed, however I did not create the post.

I can safely say that I have never posted anything relating to SharePoint, I have put in a lot of effort to avoid SharePoint at all costs :).

[image]

Comment: [link to (deleted) question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31286557/how-to-use-update-method-instead-of-add-in-sharepoint-on-job-timer-using-vis)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is due to an [edit you made](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8720601).

An edit gives you +2 reputation points when it is approved.
If the edited post is later deleted, the points are removed.

Comment: Thank you for the speedy answer, it makes sense now. I will mark it as an answer in 10 minutes as I have to wait.